# SVN: One source folder with two different repositories

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I'm working on two different projects using Apache SVN repository and TortoiseSVN client.

Project 1:

- src
  - Module 1
  - Module 2
  - Module 3
  - Module 4

Project 2:

- src
  - Module 1
  - Module 4
  - Module 5
  - Module 6
  - Module 7
  - Module 8

I'm looking for a way to make sure Module 1 & 4 is always synced. (If someone working on project 1 commits, project 2 should be updated accordingly).

I have experimented with svn externals, but I have multiple folders and files (not just one), so the process becomes tedious (Project 1 commits, Project 2 users have to go to individual folder/file and update).

I have read up on svnsync but unsure whether it is applicable for my situation. I am pretty new in SVN so would be glad if someone can point me to the right direction.